# Error: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [Last Name]: [Last Name]

Tags: apex, visualforce

Please help me with this.
Apex:

```
public with sharing class ContactEditController {
    public contact c {get; set;}
    public List<contact> conList {get;set;}
    public ContactEditController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
        c= new Contact();   
    }
    public PageReference dosave(){
        Insert c;
        conList= [select Id,Name,MailingCity,Email from Contact where id=:c.id];
        return null;

    }
    public pagereference cancelButton()
    {
        Pagereference cnclbutton = new Pagereference('/apex/contactdisplay');
        cnclbutton.setredirect(true);
        return cnclbutton;
    }


}
```

VF:

```
<apex:page standardController="Contact" extensions="ContactEditController">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:pageBlock title="Edit Contact" >
            <apex:pageBlockSection columns="1">
                <apex:inputField value="{!contact.FirstName}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!contact.LastName}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!contact.MailingCity}"/>
                <apex:inputField value="{!contact.Email}"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!dosave}" value="save" />
                <apex:commandButton action="{!cancel}" value="cancel" />
             </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Save Result" >
            <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!conList}" var="c">
                <apex:column headerValue="Name">
                <apex:outputField value="{!c.Name}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="MailingCity">
                <apex:outputField value="{!c.MailingCity}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column headerValue="Email">
                <apex:outputField value="{!c.Email}" />
                </apex:column>
          </apex:pageBlockTable>
         </apex:pageBlockSection>
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2):

What are you trying to achieve?

You have just initialized a contact in constructor and want to insert in doSave() method without providing value to any of Contact's fields. You must need to set the basic required field for a contact like email, lastname, address....

Seems that you are confused with

```
public contact c {get; set;}
```

And

```
 <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!conList}" var="c">
```

Both 'c' are not same.

Here is the example of using standard controller: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_controller_extension.htm

Also, if you are passing Contact id URL then replace code in constructor:

```
c = (Contact)stdController.getRecord();
```

Next question is if Contact already exists then why you are inserting it again?

Do you want to clone the record? if yes, then follow this article to clone the record: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000227675&type=1

Or do you want to just update it? If yes the update statement: `update c;`

Comment: Then mark answer as solved!